# google page pop up every ten minutes

Tags: google-chrome

Since earlier today, google chrome opens an about:blank page (which is my set home page) and then several times per minute, without any reason or initiating anything on my part, the google search page pops up one every 10 minutes or so. I would think it comes from a virus, but I haven't changed anything.

Anyone else having this problem?

It also happens when I am not doing anything on the computer, including when chrome isn't open.

Thanks

Comment: Are new tabs, or new windows occuring? Windows, I assume, because they also occur when you have the browser not running? Very strange... maybe a prank from a friend - just a guess? ;)

Comment: Please take a clock and check whether the timing is something like exactly every 10 min. I's not a virus - maybe some broken program that somehow dies every so often, but somehow starts the default browser without URL while dying. And will retry again later...

Comment: The first window to pop up is about:blank, which is what I set my home page to. If I ignore it, about 10 minutes later another window pops up and it's the google search page (No ads, not the malware type of issue) and it continues to do this if the computer is on. Another odd thing...this JUST started 2 days ago. I've restarted the computer, checked for any odd processes running and cannot figure this out. I read what you answered below but forgive me, I am not sure what I should type in the command prompt. I'm not that computer savvy but I can learn!

Comment: The command is just the `ps -opid,etime,args --columns 80 xf` - but you can add a redirection to a file `>ps-xf.out` to avoid copy and paste from the terminal scroll buffer. Append it to the command with a space between `... xf` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, strange, let's take a closed look what is starting the browser processes:

You say there are browser windows poping up on your desktop, every ten minutes or so, independent of whether you hav a browser running yourself, right?

We want to find out why it is occurring - so let's start with looking at **which program runs** the browsers.

If you run this command, it lists the **process tree**. It is similar to the more common `ps auxf`, but leaves much information out that we do not need here.

Please run it when you did not have a browser open, and shortly after a window poped up, while the window is still open:

```
ps -opid,etime,args --columns 80 xf
```

It lists your own processes only, as tree, so we can (mostly) see wich program has started which other.
The first column shows the process id, the second one the time that has elapsed since the programm was started.

The output is in a pretty compact form, so you can add it to the question.

**[ to be continued ... ]**

---

Based on the result, we'll continue to chase that ghost!

Answer (score -1):

Found what was wrong. I had an app installed from a company I do work for and we no longer needed it. It was designed to log the activity with the other companies we interfaced with so we could get paid for the time. the contract ended and I forgot to uninstall it. I got rid of it and the problem stopped. I remembered when I did the process list.